# Are there any floor reinforcement considerations when moving laundry to 2nd floor?

Tags: structural, support, laundry

I’m looking at moving laundry from first floor to 2nd floor in a 2 story house built in 1996. Current laundry is on the perimeter of the house right behind the garage. I plan to move it directly above that room upstairs into a closet. Are there additional floor support considerations?

Comment: Note that it may cause additional vibration and noise, and it increases risk of water damage in the event of a leak.

Comment: I’d install a water catching pan that ties into the drain (in addition to having a leak alarm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to gauge the soundness of your existing floor.

There are no special additions required to a floor system when installing a washer/dryer.